# How can i read .docx file?

Tags: c#, docx

I have a .docx file and it contains many email addresses to which i want to bulk mail. How can i read docx file through c#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en)

Get [Code Snippets for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=78BEA298-A3F9-44CF-BDE0-B4F30DC986DF&displaylang=en) for some examples

And I would highly recommend downloading the Open XML SDK productivity tool which will help you understand how the Open XML files are structured, and can even help you generate source code to use with the SDK based on the structure of your documents. You can download the tool from the same page as the SDK. It's 100MB, but it's worth the download.

Comment: I installed the SDK which is of 3 MB. But can you tell me where can i find examples of it? How do i use it?

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional info.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use [Docx](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx) library, it is very good and easy to use.

For samples guiding how to use and many examples and videos, check their [GitHub](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx) page. For download, you could [download from here](http://docx.codeplex.com/downloads/get/330961)

Comment: DocX seems to be the most popular package on nuget.

Comment: Actually there are more popular packages like [GemBox.Document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Document/) (its reading example is available [here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-open-read-word-file/301)) and [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/) (its examples are available [here](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/tree/master/examples)).

Answer (score 7):

You can read Microsoft Office files through Interop, and Office >2007 files through Open XML as well:

- **Interop**: http://blogs.techrepublic.com/howdoi/?p=190
- **Open XML**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I know this is a very old post, but this information might help others who are searching the forums.

Use [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/word-reader/wiki/Home/) library from Sourceforge.
Add a reference to that library, and then:

`Code7248.word_reader.TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor(filePath);`

`string contents = extractor.ExtractText();`

Answer (score 5):

docx files are in fact archives.

You can unzip them into their composite XML files and read through the relevant XML file (file.docx\word\document.xml)) and pull out the email addresses.

This library will help you to unzip the archive: [.Net Zip Library](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

Answer (score 3):

Office 2007 and above follow OpenXML format. you need Packaging API to open and read document parts

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx

http://openxmldeveloper.org

Answer (score 2):

There is free way to read doc & docx file, It could help you.

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile("yourfile.docx");
```

http://freeword.codeplex.com/

Comment: The "free" (closed source) version has several limitations. On codeplex there are only some samples of use of that closed source library.