# Advanced searching in Word documents

Tags: c#, search, ms-word

I have to build an application in C#.NET with which i can search for certain words in a Word document. I've seen that there are API's for this in C#.NET. But i need to take this a step further.

One thing i want to be able to do is search with a regex string.

And another thing i need to do is search for a range of numbers. So i should be able to say something like `>500`. And it should then find every "word" that has a larger value than `500`.

So the last two things are my problem. I couldn't find any direct info about this. Is it possible to search in a Word document using regex with C# code? And is there a good way to specify a range if numbers that it should find?

I want to do this in C#.NET.

Any info on this is appreciated!

Comment: Hi w00, I do not know how to open Word documents, but as soon as you open them you can read all the data to a string variable then split it into an array of strings based on "space" which means you have all words, each in a string member of an array, then you can enumerate in the array and check each word to see if it is valid by your needs, if this helps tell me to upload the code.

Comment: @mahditahsildari Hi, thanks. I like your idea. I'm going to try it out. But if you have any code which could help me on my way then yes, please do post it. It will most likely also help others in the future.

Comment: OK friend i'll do it in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

I've done it on a `.txt` file, you must change first line of code and open the word file however it should be :

```
string fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\1\1.txt");  
        string[] words = fileData.Split(' ');  
        List<int> integers = new List<int>();  
        foreach (string word in words)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                int integer = int.Parse(word);  
                if(integer > 500)  
                    integers.Add(integer);  
            }  
            catch (Exception)  
            {  
                //some code maybe 
            }  
        }  
        foreach (int integer in integers)  
        {  
            MessageBox.Show(integer.ToString());  
        }
```

and for opening word documents take a look at [how to read .docx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633615/how-can-i-read-docx-file).

Comment: dear @w00 this solution works with strings so as soon as you fetch data from your `.docx` file you'll be able to run this code on it, i added a link up here, you can find out how to open Docx files there. good lock