# How to read docx document using Visual C# code

Tags: c#, xml, docx

Ive been trying to find any tutorial or help for how to read docx document, read its content including paragraphs, headers, list etc. I have done this with xml files using System.XML; and class XMLTextReader. But how I can do this with docx documents in Visual C#?

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx and please learn to use google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633615/how-can-i-read-docx-file

Comment: Sorry, ive googled a lot but I felt like Ive found something else. Or I just couldn't understand the documentation for this what I've found. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

I have used http://docx.codeplex.com/ library to do this (read a .docx file, change the contents, save it back).

Answer (score 0):

Try these libraries:

1. [Open XML Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295%28office.12%29.aspx)
2. [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)