# the best way to format a word document for read in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, document, docx

I want to let my clients create a word document, that I will be able to read (in c#) and save to DB
for example, the client will write a meeting summary and I will save the relevant decisions and tasks to relevant users
The client insists on using word, but he is willing to use any format I want

1. What is the best fomat? Word template? Forms? Hard coded texts? And how I have to prepare the format to input the data?
2. What is the best way to read the formatted documents later?

EDIT: I see I was not clear enough

I need a way to parse a word document. For example: I need to find in the document the user name, then find the date, then the subject, then save them all.
I don't want to have (or want to have minimal) text searches, because I want to support more than one language and because I don't want to deal with spelling mistakes and because it sounds stupid.

I am actually looking for the right way to create kind of "template" that the client will be able to fill and I will be able to read.
When I say "right way" or "best way" I mean a way that would be easy for me to develope yet easy for my client to fill and then for me to read and save.

I know years ago there were ".dot" files, but as far as I remember they were hard to maintain or disribute. Are they my only choice?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you mean by _"reading the (formatted) documents"_. Will your C# code just transfer them as BLOBs to the database? Or will you actually have to extract or modify text/formatting from them?

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no "best way" to do something; it all depends on what *exactly* you want to do, and how. What is important to you: speed of development? Quality and readibility of your code? Terms of use (the "legal stuff") of the libraries involved? Longevity/availability of a library (making sure you're investment in learning a library won't be lost after a few months) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the customer after all the reasoning insist on using Word, you should check out content controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg605189%28v=office.14%29.aspx

https://dbe.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that you are not just going to treat the customers' documents as BLOBs that you have to transfer to and from the database (though it's not quite clear in your question just what you need to do with the documents).

Since your customer insists on using Word, let's consider a few options you have:

- plain text (`.txt`)
- the old, proprietary document format (`.doc`)
- the Open XML document format (`.docx`)

The first shouldn't even be an option, since the customer wants to use Word, not Notepad. There's an capability that Word has over Notepad, namely that of adding formatting to a document. I dare say your customer is quite likely to want that, so plain text might not suffice.

The second is an option, but manipulations and modifications to such documents are difficult, basically because you're dealing with an arcane proprietary format that might not have many libraries available. The easiest option would be to use Interoperability between Office and .NET.

The last option might be your best bet. There is an [official SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) available for handling Open XML documents. Google for Open XML and you should be able to find tutorials and documentations how to deal with Open XML.

Comment: perfect explanation for question 2.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read `docx` in `C#` look here: [How can i read .docx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633615/how-can-i-read-docx-file)

Next problem: format. If you have single document it is quite easy. Create empty document then remove in provided document text from an empty document.

For example create document:

```
First name:
Last name:
```

Then someone will provide information to that document creating:

```
First name: John
Last name: Smith
```

You know how empty documents looks, so what you now want is the difference. Removing empty document from provided document will give you:

```
 John
 Smith
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean "Create empty document then remove in provided document text from an empty document"

Comment: @bniyadev I updated my answer with an example

Comment: ok I got you, please see my edit to the original post