# How to read text from word file? C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a text from document file in C#

1. I can't create new Document in C#.
   I try to using "using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
   or "using System.Windows.Documents" but it does'nt recognize the code "Document doc=new Document".
2. In addition how can I read a text from .docx file?

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; //didnt recognize "Office"



namespace DocumentTest1
{
    /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

     Application word = new Application();
     Document doc = new Document();
  }
```

}

---

What could be the problem? tnx

Comment: you didn't add the reference?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633615/how-can-i-read-docx-file

Comment: I add the reference "Microsoft Office List 16.0". Do I need something else?

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please see below code

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref readFromPath);

foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in doc.Paragraphs)
    data.Add(objParagraph.Range.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: tnx. but the row "Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref readFromPath);" doesnt work as I mentioned before. maybe I have a problem with the reference but I dont found the match reference.

Comment: I just wanted to read text simple and just saw complicated solutions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633615/how-can-i-read-docx-file . This one by using iteration of paragraphs is perfect to return plain text of word file.

Comment: @Nasenbaer If you got the answer what you were looking please upvote for the answer thanks !