# read multiple word files content and write to multiple html files in c#

Tags: c#

How do I read content from multiple .docx files and write to same number of multiple HTML files keeping the content structure the same?

I've used StreamReader and StreamWriter for this purpose.

Comment: The same as you do with one file, jsut with a loop to itterate over the world files. This question is way to open ended for an answer.

Comment: You're going to need to use a library to properly read a docx file, as they are not plain text, see [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633615/how-can-i-read-docx-file) for  suggestions, and if you use the docx library suggested, [this](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html) will be helpful